# Console.log prints [Object SequelizeInstance:User]

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So, I'm a little new with sequelize. Previously (I don't know could be an older version or some other code) the `console.log` would print the whole object with all of its metadata properties but as of now it prints `[object SequelizeInstance:users]`.

I have tried using the `raw:true` property (to escape the metadata hell) which returns an [object Object] and then wrapping it with `util.inspect` it to print it.

Code:

```
User.findOne({
        attributes : [
            [sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('id')), 'id']
        ],
        raw: true //if enabled
    })
    .then(function(user){
    //returns [object SequelizeInstance:users] or if raw:true then [object Object]
        console.log("User object is "+user);
    //both are printed easily with this
        console.log(util.inspect(user,false,null));
    //OR
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, 4))
    })
```

Is this the only way to log the user object or am I missing something because previously I could just `console.log(user)` to get all the data (metadata hell)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First Diff b/w ( raw : true ) AND ( raw : false or nothing )** :

```
// When raw : true --> Will return plain json object nothing added from sequlize 
console.log("User object is "+user);

// When raw : false --> Will return sequlize object , so that you can perform verious opreation upon them
console.log("User object is "+user);
user.update({ name : 'New Name' }) // <-- Like this , you dont need to define where , coz its already object that is returned by sequlize
```

---

**Reason why are you getting [Object Object] and [object SequelizeInstance:users] is :**

```
console.log("User object is "+user); // Will show [Object Object] cos you are appending object with string
console.log("User object is " , user); // This will print out whole object clearly
```

Comment: Yup. Does the job perfectly. Also, I found out instead of using `raw:true` while querying we can use `user.get({raw:true})` to return the plain JSON object while keeping the sequelize instance available.

Answer (score 1):

> Previously [...] the `console.log` would print the whole object

I doubt you used this exact statement:

> `console.log("User object is "+user);`

Here, first thing JS does is to consider `"User object is "+user`, so it casts `user` to a string because of the `+` operator, *then* it passes the concatenated *string* to `console.log`.

If you try `console.log(user);` it should then have the expected output. You may also provide several arguments so each one is logged "as is", useful to keep track of what's being displayed without interfering with the logged data: `console.log("User object is", user);`

Comment: Yup. I can still access the same way. +1 for explanation